# SQL - WHERE Condition on SUM()

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, conditional-statements

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  `e`.*, 
  `rt`.`review_id`, 
  (SUM(vt.percent) / COUNT(vt.percent)) AS rating 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN `rating_option_vote` AS `vt`
  ON vt.review_id = e.review_id 
WHERE (rating >= '0') 
GROUP BY `vt`.`review_id`
```

In particular I would like to put a where condition on the division result value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT e.*, rt.review_id, (SUM(vt.percent) / COUNT(vt.percent)) AS rating 
FROM catalog_product_entity AS e 
INNER JOIN rating_option_vote AS vt ON e.review_id = vt.review_id 
GROUP BY vt.review_id
HAVING (SUM(vt.percent) / COUNT(vt.percent)) >= 0
ORDER BY (SUM(vt.percent) / COUNT(vt.percent)) ASC
```

Note: Added where to put `ORDER BY` statement

The query optimizer should also not calculate the Average multiple times either, so that should not be a concern here.

As was mentioned in @jagra's answer, you should be able to use `AVG()` instead of `SUM() / COUNT()`

Comment: @Francesco: Sorry, I needed to use the HAVING instead of the WHERE clause - I updated my answer

Comment: @Francesco Sure, what would you like to sort by? Just put your `ORDER BY` after the `HAVING`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
  `e`.*, 
  `rt`.`review_id`, 
  (SUM(vt.percent) / COUNT(vt.percent)) AS rating 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN `rating_option_vote` AS `vt`
  ON vt.review_id = e.review_id 
GROUP BY `vt`.`review_id` 
HAVING rating >= 0;
```

As your question is tagged MySQL this solution should work, as the documentation shows:

*...In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the HAVING clause that are not named in the GROUP BY clause. A MySQL extension permits references to such columns to simplify calculations. ...*

This extension is enabled by default on official MySQL compilation.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html (on the first occurrence of the word `HAVING` on the page)

Comment: But aren't you still running into the issue where `rating` is an invalid identifier?

Comment: As from MySQL the HAVING clause applies to this case as expected. I just found that on standard SQL the HAVING clause must refer to some named column in GROUP BY. I don't know if other RDBMS works like MySQL in this case...

Comment: Gotcha, didn't notice the MySQL part (hey I learned something :) btw, if you *were* curious, it doesn't work in Oracle)

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that about MySQL either.

Comment: @user1766760 You didn't miss the tag, `MySQL` wasn't there initially. I added it once I saw the error number the OP posted to my initial answer.

Comment: @user1766760 Yeah, I was curious about this... haha! Nice to know! In some cases I do like this as I'm actually working just with MySQL. This extension can also be disabled and so my solution will not work... =Z

Answer (score 1):

You need to use HAVING clause when filtering by aggregate functions:

```
SELECT 
  # `e`.*, => is this needed
  `rt`.`review_id`, 
  (SUM(vt.percent) / COUNT(vt.percent)) AS rating 
  AVG(vt.percent) AS rating1 # same as above 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN `rating_option_vote` AS `vt`
  ON vt.review_id = e.review_id 
GROUP BY `vt`.`review_id`
HAVING AVG(vt.percent) > 0
```

Two other notes:

1) SUM(x)/COUNT(x) <=> AVG(x)

2) You are including e.* in select but not in group by. MySql lets you do it but other databases wont.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` for aggregate conditions (such as the one you have)

```
SELECT `e`.*, `rt`.`review_id`, (SUM(vt.percent) / COUNT(vt.percent)) AS rating 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` 
INNER JOIN `rating_option_vote` AS `vt`
    ON vt.review_id = e.review_id 
WHERE ( rating >= '0') 
GROUP BY `vt`.`review_id'
HAVING (SUM(vt.percent) / COUNT(vt.percent)) > 0
```